# Combine Columns From Two Tables Into One AND Add Prompt to Return Records OLDER Than A Specific Year

Tags: ms-access

I've been at this for almost two days and I keep getting all sorts of errors in Access. So I am asking for your help. Not sure if this is even possible. THANKS

I have three tables.
[image: Data Tables]

**The Ask**
I would like to build a query to combine the data in ContractData and InvoiceData tables (see Query 1 Table).

When I run the query, Access should prompt me to enter the DocumentDate YEAR (ie. 2018) and return all records that are older than said YEAR (ie. 2018).

If ties exists for the same ID, then there is no preference as to which record is returned.

If there are no records for an ID with a DocumentDate, then Access should remove duplicates and return only one (no preference as to which record is returned).  (See The Ultimate Result Table)

[image: Results]

Comment: Sample data should be included in question as text tables (or SQL statements to create and add data), not images.

Comment: Need rules. In result: Why do 102 and 105 show Executed and not other status? Why would 105 show 12/31/2026 with Executed instead of Superseded? Why does 124 show Complete and not Pending? Apparently there is some preference for which record is returned. Do these tables have autonumber field to provide unique identifier? If not, will probably have to add.

Comment: What SQL have you tried? A UNION query will produce the Query1 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to produce what you’re looking for, though it’s a multi-step process.

But first, Name is a reserved word in Access. I changed the Name field to SupplierName in all 3 of your example tables.

Field names will need to be the same in the ContractData and InvoiceData tables for this to work as described below.

I also setup a unique primary key (AutoNumber) in each table. Will probably still work without, but I didn’t try it, and would not recommend going forward without each record uniquely identified.

Now for the fun parts…

Step 1: create a Union Query.

Create ->

Query Design ->

Close the Show Table window without adding anything.

Top left of the screen click SQL View.

Delete what’s there, and paste the following:

```
SELECT ID, SupplierName, DocumentDate, DocumentNumber, DocumentStatus
FROM ContractData

UNION 

SELECT ID, SupplierName, DocumentDate, DocumentNumber, DocumentStatus
FROM InvoiceData;
```

Click Run.

This should now be the data shown in your Query 1 Table example.

Close this query and save as Query1Table (or whatever name you want).

Step 2, create a second query, using the query we just crated (Query1Table):

Create ->

Query Design ->

Close the Show Table window without adding anything

Top left of the screen click SQL View

Delete what’s there, and paste the following:

```
SELECT Query1Table.ID, Query1Table.SupplierName, First(Query1Table.DocumentDate)
 AS FirstOfDocumentDate, First(Query1Table.DocumentNumber)
 AS FirstOfDocumentNumber, First(Query1Table.DocumentStatus)
 AS FirstOfDocumentStatus
FROM Query1Table
WHERE (((Year([DocumentDate]))>[Enter the DocumentDate YEAR]))
GROUP BY Query1Table.ID, Query1Table.SupplierName;
```

If you didn’t call the first query we made Query1Table, then you’ll need to adjust the above SQL statement appropriately.

Close query and save it as TheUltimateResult (or whatever you want).

When you open this query, TheUltimateResult, you’ll be prompted to enter a Year.

Enter the desired year and click OK.

All done!

Hopefully this will fulfill what you’re looking to do.

Comment: I tested this. Using FIrst() does not return the desired output.

Comment: THANKS! @Jeremy - After testing this, I noticed TheUltimateResult query is not returning the expected results. I am basically trying to purge IDs that do not have any activity after the year I specify. So if I enter 2024, then I should only see IDs, 105 and 124 because those IDs have a DocumentDate after 2024.  Those will be the IDs we keep and 100 and 102 will be the IDs that we purge because they do not have activity after 2024.

Comment: Sorry @sdhanraj, I guess I'm unclear on what the desired output should be. In my sample database, when I enter the year of 2024, I get 2 records: one with ID 105 and one with ID 124. What do you get, and what should the output be? Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy - Thanks for your help. I was able to use excel to produce the results.